# In Perl, what is the difference between accessing an array element using @a[$i] as opposed to using $a[$i]?

Tags: perl, syntax

Basic syntax tutorials I followed do not make this clear:

> Is there any practical/philosophical/context-dependent/tricky difference between accessing an array using the former or latter subscript notation?

```
$ perl -le 'my @a = qw(io tu egli); print $a[1], @a[1]'
```

The output seems to be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$a[...]   # array element
```

returns the one element identified by the index expression, and

```
@a[...]   # array slice
```

returns all the elements identified by the index expression.

As such,

- You should use `$a[EXPR]` when you mean to access a single element in order to convey this information to the reader. In fact, you can get a warning if you don't.
- You should use `@a[LIST]` when you mean to access many elements or a variable number of elements.

But that's not the end of the story. You asked for practical and tricky (subtle?) differences, and there's one noone mentioned yet: The index expression for an array element is evaluated in scalar context, while the index expression for an array slice is evaluated in list context.

```
sub f { return @_; }

$a[ f(4,5,6) ]     # Same as $a[3]
@a[ f(4,5,6) ]     # Same as $a[4],$a[5],$a[6]
```

Comment: At the bottom is a difference noone mentioned yet.

Comment: Switching answers. Yours takes it to.. 11!

Answer (score 8):

If you turn on [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) (which you always should) you would see this:

```
Scalar value @a[0] better written as $a[0]
```

when you use `@a[1]`.

The `@` sigil means "give me a list of something." When used with an array subscript, it retrieves a slice of the array. For example, `@foo[0..3]` retrieves the first four items in the array `@foo`.

When you write `@a[1]`, you're asking for a one-element slice from `@a`. That's perfectly OK, but it's much clearer to ask for a single value, `$a[1]`, instead. So much so that Perl will warn you if you do it the first way.

Answer (score 4):

The first yields a scalar variable while the second gives you an array slice .... Very different animals!!

Comment: Actually, the `$a[1]` form yields a scalar value, not a variable.