# What is the difference between @ and $ while accessing array elements in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, scalar

I have 2 basic questions on perl variables.

```
@names = ('Super_!','Massive_@',"Black#", "Hole*");
print "Top Player: @names[0]\n";
print "Top Player: $names[0]\n";
```

Although there is no difference between output, what is the actual difference while trying to access elements @ and $.

Also, while declaring arrays of strings, what is the difference between defining element in single quote vs double quote?

Comment: [Already answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726058/in-perl-what-is-the-difference-between-accessing-an-array-element-using-ai)

Comment: Please ask unrelated questions in separate Questions.

Answer (score 0):

As you know `@` sign points out to `array` and `$` sign to `scalar`.

Since you going to access an element of an array which is `scalar` it's preferred to use `$` otherwise you will get a warning if you defined `use warnings;`.

In other words, in Perl variable's prefix represents what you want to have, no what you have.

--

Single `'` and double quotations `"` both used to define strings but double-quotation `"hello $name"` allows you to use **string interpolation**.

Comment: This answer is wrong. An `@` means multiple items, and `$` means a single item. That's why the single element access of an array is `$array[$i]` and a hash slice is `@hash{@keys}`.